# How fictionalised is "Dust Tracks on a Road"?

Tags: historical-context, zora-neale-hurston

I just finished reading Zora Neale Hurston's memoir *Dust Tracks on a Road* and I thought it seemed to be full of tall tales as well as omissions, though obviously it is based on her real life. In his afterword to the edition I read, Henry Louis Gates Jr writes

> Hurston did make significant parts of herself up, like a masquerader putting on a disguise for the ball, like a character in her fictions.

I wondered to what extent the memoir was fictionalised - is it possible to summarise the key fictions? Or would it be shorter to summarise the key facts?!